# Is there anything in java where commenting code out, that isn't ever used, changes how the code could function? Like C/C++ memory leaks?

Tags: java

So... at work we are looking at a chunk of code, that as far as we can see (logs on the server, config files, etc) cannot and does not run unless specifically told in the config file to run.  We are currently trying to work out the last of the bugs, this really main one now.  One of the things that fix this bug (only relevant part of my question) is commenting out said code that never gets run.

Edit, more info:
But when this code isn't commented out, the constructor doesn't even get created, so no logs can be seen until it is fixed.  Also, the code runs the first time without this difficulty, it is just when it is restarted.

Edit 2:
This code doesn't have any relation with the problem that is being created, it can't actually be called from what is being done.

The question I have is is there anything in java where commenting code out, that isn't ever used, changes how the code could function?  Examples would be memory leak in C/C++.

Comment: Consider Jean's answer. Easy way to check it is to just put a `throw Error("Check Stack Trace")` in the code that you're talking about, then you can run it and get a stack trace. You will see from that where the code is being called from. After you figure it out, just delete that debug line that throws the error.

Comment: @Loduwijk: `throw Error`?  Are you *mad*?!

Comment: Does your code access any variables that are used or set in other parts of the code?

Comment: @Loduwijk: That is the problem, nothing comes out of that code, it never gets called.  We can only test this live, so it is a full half an hour to an hour to get it set up to run.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Yes, but when this code isn't commented out, the constructor doesn't even get called.  <<< I will be add this to my original question as it is useful to know.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to answer this without seeing any code.

Comment: @Juhana:  That isn't possible, that is why I wanted to settle my question to anything like a memory leak.

Comment: You can't have memory leaks in code that isn't executed, but it's trivial to write code that executes differently based on whether code that is never executed gets commented out (consider using reflection to check if a never-used method exists, and then comment out the method)

Comment: It's really hard to understand this sort of problem without much more information than you seem to be willing to give. You are talking about "a constructor", but we don't know what constructor that is, we don't know the relationships between parts of the code. I think this question is unanswerable as it currently stands.

Comment: @thatotherguy: Thank you, this is what I was looking for in this question, I am just trying to cover my bases and work upward.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: I understand but that is all I can give, which is why I asked more about commented code in relation to memory leaks, I thought as much but I was never the best Java student.

Comment: @Makoto No, not mad at all. `throw new Error();` is a great way to troubleshoot bugs. Obviously you don't leave it in production code. You take <5 seconds to type it, run the program quick, get the info you need (conveniently closing at the same time), and you delete the line. I have often gotten tired of listening to other people waste time discussing how to find the problem, and I have done that to fix a bug in less than 1 minute while others are still going on about it. If the shoe fits, wear it. Obviously there are cases where you shouldn't do this, but in most cases it works fine.

Comment: Also, this has gotten to the point where we are all making wild guesses about the nature of the code. This isn't really a good question anymore unless the code is supplied or described better.

Comment: @Loduwijk I agree, my question has been answered to the fullest I hoped, anymore and everyone will need to be sitting down to look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If commenting it out corrects the bug, then this code is actually used.

Try debugging it by adding a breaking point on said unused code and see for yourself.

Comment: So, I have as much proof as I can get that this isn't ever run.  I have fully commented out the entire method and it still won't log at all, but the program runs correctly.  The logger has now problems else where in this particular object or any other for that matter.

Comment: @Lawrence I think you are just providing more evidence that it _does_ run. Something is happening, and you just don't know what. Either debug it and put breaks at the beginning of all executable code in that file, or throw errors at the beginning of all executable code in that file.

Comment: @Loduwijk: I agree with you, **but** the other devs nor I can show that it is being run, the code, logs, and runtime application doesn't show this.  We have been on this for about a week now.

Comment: @Lawrence You should be able to see a difference in the code flow between commenting the code and not commenting it since it does not provide the same output.

Comment: @JeanLogeart: I don't comment it, the whole program doesn't get run, if I comment it the program runs.  If I comment it and leave any type of output code in it, nothing ever gets printed, no system commands get run, no logs get filled, nothing.

Comment: what does compile say? what error message do you get?

Comment: @JeanLogeart:  No compile messages, no error messages.  It only has problems during runtime in the actual environment application.

Comment: @Lawrence How do you know the code is not used in this environment then?

Comment: @JeanLogeart: [See above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31168373/is-there-anything-in-java-where-commenting-code-out-that-isnt-ever-used-chang#comment50345369_31168451)

Answer (score 3):

If commenting fixes the problem, that code is definitely being used. As suggested, try putting a breakpoint or printing on said code.

> The question I have is is there anything in java where commenting code out, that isn't ever used, changes how the code could function?

When you comment, the compiler ignores everything commented so, you code **does** change; you are 'deleting' a portion of code.

Answer (score 1):

By its very nature, commenting code out changes out a program runs.  If the code was there previously and it was doing some operation that was deemed critical, and it's subsequently commented out, you have indeed changed how the code could function.

If it were the case that the code was **never used**, then commenting it out would have the same effect as deleting it; that is, it wouldn't change the behavior at all.  You would require a regression test to ensure this, though.

Your scenario is the opposite of that, the code is *very much* in use.

Now, the likelihood of that introducing new and aberrant behavior is strongly dependent on what test suite you have to ensure that regressions don't occur.  If there is no test suite, you have to take ***extra*** precautions to ensure that the undesirable behavior is corrected.

In practice, however, you should avoid commenting code out in favor of using your VCS tool (Subversion, Git, Mercurial, etc) to resurrect it should it be needed again.

Comment: I have a feeling you misunderstand the question. OP says that commenting out the code *fixes* the problem, and that the code being commented out is *not used*.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: I'm not so sure I've misunderstood, but I'll re-read the question.  If commenting it out has fixed the problem, then yes, the program has indeed changed.  If that's introduced a regression or any other problems, the correct answer is **we don't know**; it strongly depends on what that commented code was actually doing.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Actually, the OP seems to be implying that the code _does_ get used despite saying that it doesn't. Saying "Commenting out this code that **never runs** fixes a bug" just doesn't make sense. It has to be doing something, somewhere, somehow, so I would be very hesitant to go ahead with this "fix." It requires more investigation into their specific problem.

Comment: @Loduwijk: is right, but I can just not prove anywhere that this is being called, nor should it even effect what is being done.  It is irrelevant code.

Comment: @Lawrence: Hope you've got tests around that code.  I'd hate to make a change like that to fix one thing only to break ten others.

Comment: @Makoto: There are, but none that are raised when compiling or testing, only in actual runtime does it exhibit these problems.

Comment: @Lawrence it sounds like you don't really have the tests you need to guard against a scenario like this.  My advice stands above though;  if you comment code out and the behavior changes, then you've changed how the program runs.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the potential need for that code later on, I can see no reason it would effect your final product.  When cleaning up legacy code, I often comment out blocks that I think are unused, then do a clean compile to test if it actually needed anywhere.  So I think your safe amusing that commented out code doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: It is in the past releases and it has it's uses that we would like to keep.

Comment: Then Jene below is probably right, you need to plug it into a debugger and figure out whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

Open the code in an editor that allows you to see what the usages of the code are. For example, if you use Netbeans, right-click a method declaration and select "Find Usages" to see all the places in your code that call that method.

If the code is in fact executing and commenting it out fixes one known bug, I would be very leery of going ahead with that route without knowing how or why the code is executing or how or why the bug is occurring.

I'll repeat what I said in a comment above: check the stack trace in the code in question.

And a few things to look for since there are some pitfalls you might not be thinking about...

Even if there are no usages of the methods in your file, you could be triggering code to run from elsewhere without realizing it. You could have properties which are defined where they are declared which will execute code, or you could have static code.

```
public class MyClass
{
    { System.out.println("This text will output even if you never create a MyClass instance. The class just needs to be loaded."); }

    private static JFrame jframe = new JFrame(); // similar thing here as above; JFrame() constructor is executed, possibly without you even realizing when or how

    private ContentPane pane = jframe.getContentPane(); // called when object instantiated, even if you don't do anything else to it, even though this is not in its constructor

    { jframe.setVisible(true); }
}
```

The above code will output a message to standard output, will create *and show* a window, and when you create an instance of this class it will execute JFrame's getContentPane() even though this class has no constructor to tell it to do so, because of the way the property is defined.

So you see, there are multiple places where executed code could be hidden. Again, you need to understand your problem more before you should feel safe just deleting (that's essentially what commenting-out is) code.

Comment: It hasn't shown anything yet, which is why I brought my question here.